# where can I find SDK folder in Eclipse Android FileExplorer

Tags: android

I am working on Android application which  needs to play audio present in cal folder i.e sfdk folder. My doubt is wehere can I find SDK folder in File/Explorer option of 
ddms.I find data and system folders in File/Explorer, but didnot find SDK folder.Can  I be helped to sove this issue .
Thanks N Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean the Android APIs which are available with the sdk?

It is present in the project folder in Eclipse.(*Couldnt post picture because of low reputation :-)*)

If you want to see the system files inside the emulator, go the command prompt and type

```
host $>adb shell
#>ls
```

You can see all the system files.

If you want to see the Android sdk, you should download the source code from the Android site.http://source.android.com/source/download.html

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 0):

DDMS displays the content of your phone's internal disk space. There should be a folder named /sdcard that represents the sdcard, if you have one mounted on your phone or emulator.

If by "SDK folder" you mean the SDK that you installed on your PC, it's not going to be shown my DDMS. Feel free to clarify your question.

Comment: Its not SDK that is installed,it is the sdcard folder that represents Sdcard.I am not able to find this folder in DDMS. How can I find this folder?When I open fileexplorer ,I am able to view data and system folders which are expandable.But when I expand those folders,I am not able to find sdcard folder.Where can I find this folder?